# InvalidOperation at [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>] in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm developing an app in Django and I'm having this error when the form is submitted:

[image]

I'll share you my code

This is my model:

```
class Oferta(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(verbose_name='Título', max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name='Descripción', null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad', null=False, blank=False, default=1)
    valor = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Valor', max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    material = models.CharField(verbose_name='Material', max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=MATERIAL_CHOICES)
    imagenes = models.ManyToManyField(ImagenesOferta, verbose_name='Imagenes de la Oferta', blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, verbose_name='Usuario', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo/Inactivo', default=True)
    vendido = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Vendido', default=False)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de Creación', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Oferta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ofertas',
        ordering = ['-fecha_creacion']
```

This is my view:

```
login_required(login_url='login')
def publish_offer(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        titulo = request.POST['titulo']
        descripcion = request.POST['descripcion']
        cantidad = request.POST['cantKilos']
        valor = request.POST['valor']
        material = request.POST['material']
        imagenes = request.FILES['imagenes']
        usuario = request.user

        oferta = Oferta(titulo=titulo, descripcion=descripcion, cantidad=cantidad, valor=valor, material=material, usuario=usuario)
        oferta.save()

        for imagen in imagenes:
            
            img = ImagenesOferta.objects.create(imagen=imagen)
            oferta.imagenes.add(img)
```

And this is the fragment of my form that I think that could be tha problem:

```
<div class="col-xl-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="valor" class="form-label">Agregar valor</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                            id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="0.00$">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

By aesthetic and styling questions i decided to use a normal form

Comment: This is one of the *very many* reasons to use (`Model`)`Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *strongly* advise to use a `ModelForm`, since this will perform the necessary validation and cleaning of the data.

```
from django import forms


class OfertaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Oferta
        fields = ('titulo', 'descripcion', 'cantidad', 'valor', 'material')
```

In the HTML form, you will only have to rename `name="cantKilos"` to `name="cantidad"`, but there is not much reason to use a different name anyway.

In the view, we can then simply make use of the form, you *don't* have to use the form in the template if you don't want to:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def publish_offer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OfertaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.usuario = request.user
            offerta = form.save()
            imgs = [
                ImagenesOferta(imagen=imagen)
                for image in request.FILES.getlist('imagenes')
            ]
            ImagenesOferta.objects.bulk_create(imgs)
            oferta.imagenes.add(*img)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    # otherwise this is a GET request, or the form was invalid
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!!!! this helped me!!! you are an angel!!! I'm so grateful!!!